# simple VB code help

Tags: vb.net

I  am a java devloper and I wish to convert following code to java
can any VB devloper tell me what following does?

```
    temp8Bit = 0
    temp8Bit = Convert.ToByte(tempRMACode.ToCharArray().GetValue(0))
             + Convert.ToByte((tempRMACode.ToCharArray()).GetValue(7))
    rmaValidationCode += String.Format("{0:X2}", temp8Bit)
```

tempRMACode is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is adding the byte values of the 1st and the 8th characters of tempRMACode, then appending it to rmaValidationCode in the format of "0:X2" which is a 2-character hexadecimal  representation of the string (temp8Bit).

Answer (score 1):

What it's going to do is take the 0th & 7th character from the tempRMACode string, convert those values to Bytes and then add them.  Convert is applied to the ASCII value of the character.  So `Convert.ToByte("A") == 65` the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `A`.

`String.Format("{0:X2}", temp8bit)` is going to take the numeric value of `temp8bit` and give you the HEX value.  So if you had the number 121 in temp8bit, you'd get 79 in rmaValidationCode.

---

Given the following:

```
Dim temp8bit As Byte
Dim tempRMACode As String = "A234567890"

Dim rmaValidationCode As String = String.Empty

temp8Bit = 0
temp8bit = Convert.ToByte(tempRMACode.ToCharArray().GetValue(0)) _
     + Convert.ToByte((tempRMACode.ToCharArray()).GetValue(7))

Dim a As String = tempRMACode.ToCharArray().GetValue(0)
Dim b As String = tempRMACode.ToCharArray().GetValue(7)

Dim c As Byte = Convert.ToByte(tempRMACode.ToCharArray().GetValue(0))
Dim d As Byte = Convert.ToByte(tempRMACode.ToCharArray().GetValue(7))

rmaValidationCode += String.Format("{0:X2}", temp8bit)
```

the output is:

```
temp8bit = 121 or 0x79
a = "A"
b = "8"
c = 65
d = 56
rmaValidationCode = "79"
```